# HTML5 email pattern attribute for my school email

Tags: php, html, attributes

I want to make user only enter my school email using pattern attribute.
The pattern should look like "XXXXX@auburn.edu". XXXXX could be letters (lowercase, uppercase ) or numbers. I have the first part: [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}. I am not sure how to add @auburn.edu

```
    <div class="well" style="margin-top: 50px;">
      <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputAUEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Auburn Email*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="student_email" name="student_email" placeholder="XXXXX@auburn.edu" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}">
            </div>
            </div>
    
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Anything you do in there in javascript will have to be done again on the server as there is no way to stop people sending data that looks like its from this form but is built somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex expression:

**Expression:**

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}@(auburn\.edu)$"
```

- @ = value must have '@' char in it
- (auburn.edu) = regex group for a specified string
- $ = to tell end of string

Comment: You don't need the `(` and `)`, but you _do_ need to escape the `.` - otherwise, `12345@auburnXedu` will also match, because `.` means "any character".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have "php" tag on question, I think this method you might can try.

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;

// List of allowed e-mail domains
$allowdomain = [
    'auburn.edu'
];

// To check  the address is an valid address
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    // Separate email by "@" characters ( As there should be only one "@")
    $parts = explode('@', $email);

    // Removes and return the domain
    $domain = array_pop($parts);

    // Check if the domain is in our list
    if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowdomain))
    {
        // Not allowed. So add your not allowed output msg or alert here
    }
}
```

domain means "@auburn.edu" on your question. "allowdomain" is an array to put any of those domains that need to check. If you need to add more domains, it should be look like,

```
$allowdomain = [
    'auburn.edu',
    'site.ca',
    'site2.us'
];
```

Comment: Yes, I know that we can use php to filter out the email data. But I just want to see if it is possible to use html pattern attribute to filter out the email.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, anything that doesn't have a special meaning just means itself. So the pattern for exactly the word "auburn" is simply `auburn`. The `@` character also has no special meaning, so that's easy too.

However, a `.` *does* have a special meaning (it means "any single character"), so you have to "escape" it as `\.`

Putting that on the end of your existing pattern is then really simple:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}@auburn\.edu"
```

Note: **client-side for convenience; server-side for security**. The validation provided in the browser is extremely trivial for anyone to ignore; it's helpful to spot mistakes, because it's fast, but it's completely useless for actually being certain.

To check on the server, you need to check the same thing in PHP, using [`preg_match`](https://php.net/preg_match), e.g.

```
if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}@auburn\.edu$/', $_POST['student_email'] ) {
    echo 'E-mail address not allowed!';
    exit;
}
```

Note the extra `^` and `$` which match "beginning of string" and "end of string", so that the pattern rejects things like "hello-12345@auburn.edu.nonsense" which only *contain* the required address.